# Joomla 3 form field set size not working

Tags: joomla, size, field

This my field declaration for my component:

```
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_VIAE_CONTACT_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>
                        <![CDATA[COM_VIAE_CONTACT_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
    <!-- http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types -->
    <fields name="request">
        <fieldset name="request">
            <field name="NO_RECEIVERS_ERROR_STRING" type="text"
                label="NO_RECEIVERS_ERROR_STRING_LABEL"
                description="NO_RECEIVERS_ERROR_STRING_DESC"
                default="Er zijn geen ontvangers configureerd!"
                required="true" size="100">
            </field>
```

The `size="100"` attribute is not taken into account when I look at the admin page of this component.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try giving it a class and setting the size using css

Comment: Where do I put that css file: in the admin part or in the site part?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Joomla and would be better off on [the Joomla Q&A StackExchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla 3.x use [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) in the admin area.

So, add a class option to your `XML` for your field, e.g. here's the definition of a `textarea` note the `span6` in the `class` attribute:

```
<field
    name="file_exclusions"
    label="COM_EASYSTAGING_LOCALSITE_FILE_EXCLUSIONS"
    description="COM_EASYSTAGING_LOCALSITE_FILE_EXCLUSIONS_DESC"
    type="textarea"
    class="inputbox span6"
    default=""
    rows="10"
    cols="50"
/>
```